# Get inbox messages from a date onwards

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the Graph API Explorer, and using `GET /me/inbox`, I can get a list of messages.

I was wondering how to **limit** them to messages from the past day, for example?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [time based paging](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/) this way:

[`me/inbox?since=1372395600`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/inbox?since=1372395600)

It relies on the `updated_time` (unix timestamp) parameter of an inbox thread. This way you could get all the threads updated with a message at a time since yesterday, for example.

Comment: As Unix time stamp returns seconds since Jan 1, 1970 we can  subtract 24*60*60 from the current time stamp and pass it as argument to since parameter to get messages since the pass day